# If $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $R^3$, simplify the expression $(u+v) \times (u-v)$ as much as possible.

Tags: cross-product

Here is my thinking process for answering this question:

Cross product is neither *commutative* nor *associative*. Hence I cannot do any algebraic operations on this expression. However I know that cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to both of them.

On the other hand I know that $u-v = u + (-v)$ Therefore $u+v$ and $u-v$ are located are collinear with each other.

How can I use this information to simplify this expression?

Comment: The cross product is distributive though. Not to mention anti-commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
&(u +v) \times (u - v)\\
=& u \times u + v \times u - u \times v - v \times v\\
=& 0 + v \times u - u \times v - 0\\
=& v \times u - u \times v\\
=& v \times u + v \times u\\
=& 2 (v \times u)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I cannot understand how you went form $-u \times v$ to $v \times u$. Because order of cross product is important. One should not change the order.

Comment: $u \times v = - v \times u$ or equivalently $ - u \times v = v \times u$ is a basic property of cross products.

Comment: I did not know that. Does this property has a name?

Comment: Anti-commutativity.